# How to remove codes in my Generated Excel File

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel

I have an issue regarding the table2excel (https://github.com/rainabba/jquery-table2excel) library. The codes are also being printed in the generated excel file.

Here is the problem:
https://imgur.com/a/oMIR2VU

Here is my code,

```
$('#to_excel').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    $("#jv_table").table2excel({
       name: "JV SUMMARY",
       filename: "jv_summary_excel.xls", // do include extension
       preserveColors: false // set to true if you want background colors and font colors preserved
     });
})
```

my table:

```
<?php if(!isset($_GET['summary'])) {
            foreach($newArr as $arr){
                if(array_keys(array_values($arr)[0])[0] =="GL ACCOUNT" || array_keys(array_values($arr)[0])[0] == "COST CENTER") continue;
                ?>
                <tr class="<?=array_keys(array_values($arr)[0])[0] == "A/P - KLASSIC" ? "end" : ""?>">
                    <td><?=explode('_',array_keys($arr)[0])[0]?></td> <!-- DEPARTMENT -->
                    <td><?=$gl_accounts[array_keys(array_values($arr)[0])[0]]?></td> <!-- GL ACCOUNT NUMBERS -->
                    <td><?=array_keys(array_values($arr)[0])[0]?></td> <!-- GL ACCOUNT NAMES -->
                    <td><?=$cost_centers[explode('_',array_keys($arr)[0])[0]]?></td> <!-- COST CENTER -->
                    <td><?=$profit_centers[explode('_',array_keys($arr)[0])[0]]?></td> <!-- PROFIT CENTER (P90-SOMETHING) -->
                    <td><?=number_format((array_values(array_values($arr)[0])[0] * 0.32),2)?></td>
                    <td><?=number_format((array_values(array_values($arr)[0])[0] * 0.20),2)?></td>
                    <td><?=number_format((array_values(array_values($arr)[0])[0] * 0.20),2)?></td>
                    <td><?=number_format((array_values(array_values($arr)[0])[0] * 0.26),2)?></td>
                    <td><?=number_format((array_values(array_values($arr)[0])[0] * 0.02),2)?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php }} ?>
```

I also check my table and there is no code in there. I want to remove it as soon as possible. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by switching to this library (https://codepedia.info/javascript-export-html-table-data-to-excel). The codes are gone and also the data types are formatted properly.